# How to manage users that put wrong email in registration but saved in the database

Tags: python, django, web

I write some code to register a user. In my fonction "register(request)", Before i do email verification i save the user and he is saved in the database but he is not active. Then i use this user to activate him in my function "activate(request)" and i activate the user. 
But there is a problem, if the user put a wrong or not email, he will be saved in database, and this can take useless memory space in database. And the other problem is that if the user want to correct his informations on registration page, he will not be able to do that because his username and email already exists in database.

**EDIT**
By saying that he puts a wrong email is in the case he put username@gmail.com instead of user_name@gmail.com. The email is entered and is in the good format but that is not his email

```
def register(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activez votre compte acquisitor.'
            message = render_to_string('users/acc_active_email.html',{
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return render(request, 'users/mail_registration.html')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'users/registration.html', {'user_form': form,
                                                'registered': registered})


def activate(request, uidb64, token, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        registered = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user, backend)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Lien d'activation invalide")
```

Comment: what you mean by wrong email address

Comment: if he put username@gmail.com instead of user_name@gmail.com for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the user put a wrong or not email

Your form should validate that the email field is filled and at least formally correct, so the only possibility is that the user mistyped his email. A common and effective solution (albeit slightly annoying from user's perspective) is to put 2 email fields in the form and check if they match in the form's `clean()` data.

At this point, if the user still managed to get it wrong, he won't get the activation mail anyway, so there's not much you can do - except eventually adding a cron job to remove users that never activated their accounts (based on active status, creation date and last login date).

Comment: by saying that he puts a wrong email is in the case he put username@gmail.com instead of user_name@gmail.com

Comment: But when can i know that i can suppress the users not active. I can wait indefinetely that user makes email confirmation.

Comment: As I wrote, you can check the active status, creation date and last login date (those are fields of the default `contrib.auth.User` model - which I assume you're using). If the user account has been created more than X days ago (check how long a registration token is valid, IIRC they expire at some point), is still not active and the user never logged in (last login date will be null) then obviously the user never activated the account.

Comment: Thank you very much